# Trying to build a function to simulate 100 paths of a particle in R

Tags: r, path, simulate

so basically lets say I have a function X that will calculate the random motion of a particle in 1 dimension. The function has different constants, and a normal random variable W, every path happens every  0.1ms. I want to simulate 100 paths.

```
X <- 0;
Dt <- 0.0001;
V <- 0.5;
for (j in 0:100){
    W <- rnorm(100, j*Dt*V,1);
    x[0] = 0;
    x[j] = x[j-1] + Dt*V+ W*sqrt(Dt)
}
```

But I get an error saying that "replacement has zero length", also after getting the arrya of the different positions of the particle I would like to simulate it but I am not sure on how to do this.
Thank you

Comment: In R, there is no `x[0]` but indexing starts at `x[1]`. That means that both of your second and third line in the loop body will fail. Also, you should create the vector `x` before you start the loop, i.e. via `x <- vector(length = 100)`.

Comment: Thank you for your help @M.Papenberg I added them but now I get "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length", which i dont really undestand, it happens with  my x[j] function definition line.

Answer (score 0):

```
X <- array()
Dt <- 0.0001
V <- 0.5
X[1] = 0
for (j in 2:101){
    W <- rnorm(100, j*Dt*V,1)
    X[j] = X[j-1] + Dt*V+ W*sqrt(Dt)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to do something like this:

```
X <- 0;
Dt <- 0.0001;
V <- 0.5;

LEN <- 101 
W <- rnorm(LEN - 1, Dt * V, 1) 
x <- rep(0, LEN) 
for (i in seq_len(LEN - 1)) {
  x[i + 1] = x[i] + Dt * V + W[i] * sqrt(Dt)
}
x
```